# WebRequest.GetResponse() returns empty stream result but Fiddler shows content in response

Tags: c#, web

I'm trying to save binary data recieved from remote server with code:

```
public static WebObjectResponse<byte[]> RequestBinary(string uri)
{
    var streamData = GetResponseStream(uri);
    if (streamData.StatusCode != 200)
    {
        return new WebObjectResponse<byte[]> {Result = new WebRequestResult(streamData.StatusCode)};
    }

    if (streamData.ContentLength == -1)
    {
        return new WebObjectResponse<byte[]> {Result = new WebRequestResult(204)}; // 204 = No Content
    }

    using (streamData.Stream)
    {
        var responseBuffer = new byte[streamData.ContentLength];
        streamData.Stream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
        return new WebObjectResponse<byte[]>
        {
            Data = responseBuffer,
            Result = WebRequestResult.CreateSuccessfull()
        };
    }
}

private static WebStreamResponse GetResponseStream(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var response = CreateRequest(uri).GetResponse();
        return new WebStreamResponse
        {
            StatusCode = 200,
            Stream = response.GetResponseStream(),
            ContentLength = response.ContentLength
        };
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        return new WebStreamResponse {StatusCode = (int) ((HttpWebResponse) e.Response).StatusCode};
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`response.ContentLength` has value `-1`, but Fiddler shows me another picture:

[image: Fiddler session result]

That's why i had to add a double check (response.ContentLength != -1) to prevent exception throwing.

How I have to change C# code to recieve a valid response stream?

Comment: What is the content? You can see it in the raw tab. Also it looks like you've got an image back, are you sure you are looking at the correct entry?

Comment: @JMK, if I will switch to 'Image' tab in Fiddler I will see a correct picture. If I will go to the image hotlink in browser, it will show me this image too